# Firestore security rules Multiple get() not working as expected

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

These are my firestore security rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /collectionA/{someID} {
         function checkA() {
            return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/collectionA/$(someID)/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.deleteFlag != true
         }
         function checkB() {
            return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/collectionB/$(request.auth.uid)/companies/$(someID)).data.deleteFlag != true
         }
         allow read, write: if  checkA() || checkB()
    }
  }
}
```

And this is my database objects:

```
project {
  collectionA {
    companyA {
      users {
        r9Myn4TfzAVpSZGzyaet {
          deleteFlag: false
        }
      }
    }
  }
  collectionB {
    aAzUlfztdYdEIXT3Tva73kCiuy93 {
      companies {
        companyA{
          deleteFlag:false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And I tried Simulator :

```
simulation type : get
location        : collectionA/companyA
provider        : password
Firebase UID    : aAzUlfztdYdEIXT3Tva73kCiuy93
```

I expected this security rules return "true".
Because I thought checkA returned "false" and checkB returned "true".
But they returned "false".

Please let me know if you have any  ideas or suggestions.

Comment: The title of your question is suggesting that a single get works ok, but multiple gets do not? Have you tried breaking them up individually?

Comment: Yes, my title means what you are saying. I tried "allow read, write: if  checkA()", it returned "false". And I tried "allow read, write: if  checkB()", it returned "true".

Comment: If you're convinced that it's not working the way you expect, and you have reproduction steps that illustration exactly what's gone wrong, please file a bug report.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: Thank you. I found the same problem on this site. And it doesn't resolve too. I am going to send a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

I heard that the simulator sometimes does not work properly.
I threw the query from the client and verified it and it worked correctly.
So I thought it was a bug in the simulator.
However, I received the following response from Developer Platform Support.

FYI

> The get function will get an error if trying to get a value for an
>   object that does not exist. When an error occurs in the condition
>   judgment, the security rule is not applied in the security rule.
>   Because of the specifications of security rules, it is impossible to
>   control on nonexistent objects